# MailChimp group options select in php

Tags: php, http-post, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I tried to find the answer for the last 5 hours but I finally caved in and am reaching out for help.

Basically, this code worked great until I needed to select a group option. I'm not sure if I'm creating my interests array properly, I may have to use 'merge_vars' but really would like some guidance before I spend another 5 hours blindly walking into walls.

Note for my group name I've been using the entire string "group[3117]"

Action.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$interest = $_POST['group[3117]'];

if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
    // MailChimp API credentials
    $apiKey = '+ insert api key here +';
    $listID = 'insert list id';
    $interest = 'insert group name'; // YOUR INTEREST/GROUP ID

    // MailChimp API URL
    $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

    // member information
    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $email,
        'status'        => 'subscribed',
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'     => $fname,
            'LNAME'     => $lname
        ],
            'interests'        => array(
        $interest => true
        ),
    ]);

    // send a HTTP POST request with curl
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    // store the status message based on response code
    if ($httpCode == 200) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #34A853">You have successfully subscribed to CodexWorld.</p>';
    } else {
        switch ($httpCode) {
            case 214:
                $msg = 'You are already subscribed.';
                break;
            default:
                $msg = 'Some problem occurred, please try again.';
                break;
        }
        $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">'.$msg.'</p>';
    }
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = '<p style="color: #EA4335">Please enter valid email address.</p>';
}
}
// redirect to homepage
header('location:index.php');
```

Index.php

```
<?php session_start(); // place it on the top of the script ?>
<?php
$statusMsg = !empty($_SESSION['msg'])?$_SESSION['msg']:'';
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
echo $statusMsg;
?>
<form method="post" action="action.php">
<p><label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
<p><label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lname" /></p>
<p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
<p><select name="group[3117]" class="REQ_CSS" id="mce-group[3117]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="2">Seattle</option>
<option value="4">Portland</option> </p>
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: What happens if you name your element "group" instead of "group[3117]"?

Comment: Also you're not closing your `<select>` element.

Comment: the html selection name is name="group[3117]" . i did try just group but returned an error, I'm about to try simply 3117, thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: you're right wow. give me a second.

Comment: 3117 is not a valid element name either. Just use group, and make sure you change your PHP code to match.

Comment: unfortunately that wasn't it, still get an error. Another i'm about to try is to change "interest" and "interests" to group and groupings. and I'm going to try and follow what they suggest here to a T

http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/manage-groups-in-advanced-forms

Comment: How do you know that? What errors are you seeing? You don't explain your problem in your question.

Comment: i return line 57 "some problem occurred". And it does not add any data to my mailchimp list.

Comment: That seems like an unlikely error message...

Comment: Solution: I was using the wrong interest id / group name "group[xxxx]"
Enter the MailChimp API playground. Select your list / subresources / interest-categories / interest name / subresources / interests / response . scroll down and there will be a unique id for each category.
I will post an updated solution once I've smoothed everything out.
See -http://blog.chapagain.com.np/mailchimp-api-v3-0-manage-subscriber-using-php-curl/
scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution, there's a lot of manual data entry but it works, if someone has an easier method please let me know.
Enter the MailChimp API playground. Select your list / subresources / interest-categories / interest name / subresources / interests / response . scroll down and there will be a unique "id" for interest. (ignore category id)
Here is the code, credit goes [Mukesh Chapegan](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/mailchimp-api-v3-0-manage-subscriber-using-php-curl/) and [CodexWorld](http://www.codexworld.com/add-subscriber-to-list-mailchimp-api-php/)

Name this page Action.php

```
<?php
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$memberHash = md5($email);
$first_name = $_POST['fname'];
$last_name =  $_POST['lname'];
$interest = $_POST['location'];   
$api_key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // YOUR API KEY
$server = 'us14.'; //last part of ur api key
$list_id = 'XXXXXXX'; // YOUR LIST ID
$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$api_key );   
$data = array(
    'apikey'        => $api_key,
    'email_address' => $email,
    'status'        => 'subscribed',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
        'FNAME' => $first_name,
        'LNAME'    => $last_name
        ),
    'interests'        => array(
            $interest => true
            ),
    );
$json_data = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$list_id.'/members/'.$memberHash);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result_obj = json_decode($result);
echo $result_obj->status;
echo '<br>';
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result_obj); echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Here is the HTML form. name this index.php 
Note I named the select element to location and the option values to the interest id I obtained through the API playground.

```
<?php session_start(); // place it on the top of the script ?>
<?php
    $statusMsg = !empty($_SESSION['msg'])?$_SESSION['msg']:'';
    unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    echo $statusMsg;
?>

<form method="post" action="action.php">
    <p><label>First Name: </label><input type="text" name="fname" /></p>
    <p><label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lname" /></p>
    <p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email" /></p>
 <p> <select name="location" class="REQ_CSS" id="mce-group[3117]">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="f3eb68268d">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="3204c60199">Seattle</option>
<option value="3c5b8d638a">Portland</option> </p>
</select>

    <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE"/></p>
</form>
```

If this answer helps please upvote so it's easier to find. I looked for this solution for a very very long time and found a lot of questions but few answers.